# Difference between TABLE and PL/SQL TABLE in ALL_ARGUMENTS view

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

While fetching data by query

```
select * from ALL_ARGUMENTS
```

It will return two types in **DATA_TYPE** column

1- TABLE

2- PL/SQL TABLE

I have checked through containing procedure, both types are declared in a similar way.

What is the difference between them?

Example - 
Have declaration

**TYPE Bom_Revision_Tbl_Type IS TABLE OF Bom_Revision_Rec_Type**  - PL/SQl TABLE

```
OBJECT_NAME   PKG NAME     ARGUMENT_NAME     DATA_TYPE
PROCESS_BOM  BOM_BO_PUB P_BOM_REVISION_TBL  PL/SQL TABLE
```

**TYPE inv_ebi_name_value_pair_tbl IS TABLE OF inv_ebi_name_value_pair_rec** -  SQL TABLE

```
OBJECT_NAME   PKG NAME             ARGUMENT_NAME           DATA_TYPE
ID_TO_VALUE INV_EBI_ITEM_HELPER P_PK_COL_NAME_VAL_PAIRS     TABLE
```

Comment: Alex please refer edited question

Comment: Those are both PL/SQL tables. Perhaps include the relevant entries from `all_arguments` and the matching procedure declarations?

Comment: Provide also definitions for `Bom_Revision_Rec_Type` and `inv_ebi_name_value_pair_rec`

Comment: It looks like the type definitions you've shown aren't complete - doesn't `Bom_Revision_Tbl_Type` have an `index by` clause?

Comment: Alex, I have added some query out put, please check

Comment: Yes Alex, Bom_Revision_Tbl_Type have INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER in its defination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [three collection types in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7E9034D5-0D33-43A1-9012-918350FE148C).

Your `Bom_Revision_Tbl_Type` is an [associative array](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170):

> An associative array (formerly called PL/SQL table or index-by table) is a set of key-value pairs. Each key is a unique index, used to locate the associated value with the syntax variable_name(index).

It's defined with an `index by` clause. That is still reported in `all_arguments` as a "PL/SQL table", using the old name for that collection type.

Your `inv_ebi_name_value_pair_tbl` type is a [nested table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-5ADB7EE2-71F6-4172-ACD8-FFDCF2787A37).

The documentation explains the differences between them, and when each type is appropriate; [associative arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-157A4309-1BAF-419D-8B7F-3CB4AA9921DF):

> An associative array is appropriate for:
>
> - A relatively small lookup table, which can be constructed in memory each time you invoke the subprogram or initialize the package that declares it
> - Passing collections to and from the database server

and [nested tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-70EC41EA-4ED2-42FE-A03D-6CED02C3A393):

> A nested table is appropriate when:
>
> - The number of elements is not set.
> - Index values are not consecutive.
> - You must delete or update some elements, but not all elements simultaneously.
> - Nested table data is stored in a separate store table, a system-generated database table. When you access a nested table, the database joins the nested table with its store table. This makes nested tables suitable for queries and updates that affect only some elements of the collection.
> - You would create a separate lookup table, with multiple entries for each row of the main table, and access it through join queries.

Comment: Thanks for answer Alex, can you please help me out for table where I can find both nested tables and  associative array details

Comment: As per my finding, I can say that Associative array are defined at package level, but Nested table can be defined at Schema level. How can we Identified whether it is defined at package level or Schema level.

Comment: @Afgan - look at the `type_name` and `type_subname` columns in `all_arguments`. For a schema-level nested table type, the type name will be set; for a PL/SQL nested table the type name will be the package it's defined in, and the type subname will be the actual type name. Either way you can see the type owner too.

Comment: @Afgan - in case it's not obvious, when the documentation talks about storage, joins and updates here, it is referring to collection columns in database tables, which might be confusing if you are only thinking about them from a PL/SQL programming perspective. There is no "system-generated database table" etc for a program variable.

Comment: Good point. The whole doc section needs to be read and understood really though...

Comment: @AlexPoole and William thanks, I gone through your comment and agreed with you, I just need some other means which can differentiate between PL/SQL TABLE and SQL TABLE, And yes I 'am not  using it for  PL/SQL programming perspective, I want this in my java program and have to decide data type of them.